# Aggregating Excel cell contents that match a label

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I'm sure this isn't a terribly difficult thing, but it's not the type of question that easily lends itself to internet searches.

I've been assigned a project for work involving a complex spreadsheet.  I've done the usual =SUM and other basic Excel formulas, and I've got enough coding background that I'm able to at least fudge my way through VBA, but I'm not certain how to proceed with one part of the task.

Simple version:  On Sheet 1 I have a list of people (one on each row, person's name in column A), on sheet 2 I have a list of groups (one on each row, group name in column A).  Each name in Sheet 1 has its own row, and I have a "Data Validation" dropdown menu where you choose the group each person belongs to.

That dropdown is sourced from Sheet 2, where each group has a row.  So essentially the data validation source for Sheet 1's "Group" column is just "=Sheet2!$a1:a100" or whatever.

The problem is this:  I want each group row in Sheet 2 to have a formula which results in a list of all the users which have been assigned to that group on Sheet 1.  What I mean is something the equivalent of "select * from PeopleTab where GROUP = ThisGroup".  The resulting cell would just stick the names together like "Bob Smith, Joe Jones, Sally Sanderson"

I've been Googling for hours but I can't think of a way to phrase my search query to get the results I want.

Here's an example of desired result (Dash-delimited.  Can't find a way to make it look nice, table tags don't seem to work here):

(Sheet 1)
Bob Smith           - Group 1 (selected from dropdown)
 
Joe Jones           - Group 2 (selected from dropdown)
Sally Sanderson     - Group 1 (selected from dropdown)

(Sheet 2)
Group 1             - Bob Smith, Sally Sanderson (result of formula)
Group 2             - Joe Jones (result of formula)

What formula (or even what function) do I use on that second column of sheet 2 to make a flat list out of the members of that group?

Comment: You could use ADO to query the Excel sheet.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `filter`; the only problem is that you will get the results as a column, not as a row.

Comment: ^ Not actually a problem; `transpose` to the rescue :P

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `FILTER` formula to achieve similar effects. The basic format is:

```
=FILTER(source, condition, [more conditions...])
```

This says "take my source range, and return cells that match each of these conditions".

You can refer to an entire column (the names in your first sheet, column A), and filter those values by the contents of another column (the group selected in column B on sheet1) by using `'Sheet1'!A:A` as the source, and `EQ('Sheet1'!B:B, $Ax)` as the condition, where `$Ax` is the reference to the group name in Sheet 2, column A (replace x with the row number).

For example in `sheet2` you could have something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|   A    |   B
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Group1 | =TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Sheet1'!A:A, EQ('Sheet1'!B:B, $A1)))
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Group2 | =TRANSPOSE(FILTER('Sheet1'!A:A, EQ('Sheet1'!B:B, $A2)))
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`TRANSPOSE` is needed because your source range is a column, so you get a column back from `FILTER`. Transpose just transposes that column into a row :)

As a side note, you can do other neat things with filter like find the sum of a filtered range (`=SUM(FILTER(...))`) and so on; I use this in budget spreadsheets to calculate income/expenses grouped and summed by month and category.

Disclaimer: tested in a google docs spreadsheet, as I don't have MS Excel.

Comment: This looks fantastic, and exactly like what I need, but as far as I can tell, Excel has no FILTER function for formulas (http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-functions-by-category-HP005204211.aspx).  Trying to find equivalent.

Comment: Hmm- I was afraid of that...[vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211) might be useful, but I think you would have to swap your columns (i.e. put he group in column 1 and name in column 2). Or, of using a google spreadsheet is an option... :)

Comment: I've been trying to get them to transition off Excel/Office for a while now.  Short answer:  lost cause.

I'll check out vlookup, thanks

Comment: Unless someone shows up with the right piece of Excel magic, I'm going to accept your answer, as it's a great answer (just not entirely applicable, sadly)

Comment: @Josh Unfortunately I don't have access to excel, otherwise I'd play around and try to figure out something that works. Good luck! If you figure it out, you should post your own answer and accept that one.

Answer (score 0):

In sheet 1:
VBA

```
Private Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
  if target.row =1 and target.value<>"" then target.offset(,1)=sheets("sheet2").cells(application.match(target.value,sheets("sheets").columns(1),0),2).value
End sub
```